# CAShapeLayer to change the width of different Brushes

Tags: ios, swift, cashapelayer

I am having different Texture Brushes I am having the image of those texture of each pixel of the stroke I want to assign the texture to the CGPath and change the width .
I need to assign the texture image and change the width to the slider response.

Answer (score 1):

You achieve this in the following order:

- Use `CGLayerCreateWithContext` to create a `CGLayer`, during this stage, the slider value is obtained and used as the `CGSize` in the initializer.
- Use `CGLayerGetContext` to get the context of the `CGLayer` created, then you render your brush texture with the context, for example, `CGContextDrawImage`.
- Use the completed `CGLayer` as a texture and draw it on screen with `CGContextDrawLayerAtPoint`, since you got your `CGPath`, you need to manually calculate the density of your drawing, and generate an array of `CGPoint` to be used as a parameter in the drawing function.

You may reference the [Quartz 2D Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/drawingwithquartz2d/dq_layers/dq_layers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001066-CH219-TPXREF101) by Apple.

Comment: Check the "Quartz 2D Programming Guide" link.